# How to find the loudest part of a mix?

Tags: mixing, vst, mastering

What are fastest methods to find the loudest part of the track during mixing?

Comment: By "loudest part" do you mean the section (e.g. the loud part is at 1 minute 11 seconds into the mix) or the track (e.g. the drums are the loudest)? And by "loud" to you mean subjectively (it sounds the loudest) or physically (delivers the most acoustic energy)?

Answer (score 5):

Turn your monitor level all the way down until you can't hear anything. Slowly turn it up. The first thing you hear as you turn up the monitors is the loudest thing in the mix.

Comment: The studio i worked at had some very low end speakers (i think they were pulled from old two track machines) and a few engineers i worked with would occasionally listen to one on very low levels to see if anything was really poking out. if all you hear is the snare, good chance your snare is too loud.

Comment: This assumes that the frequency response of your amp, speakers, listening environment and ears remains the same at different volumes. But afaik that's not the case; there's even a button on many home audio systems (usually labelled "loudness") to combat the change in frequency response at low volumes.